# How to properly create an audio unit extension?

Tags: ios, macos, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to create an Audio Unit Extension without success. I'm doing the following steps:

1- Creating an empty iOS project

2- Creanting an empty Audio Unit Extension with any subtype code, any manufacturer code, and Effect Audio Unit type

3- After that I'm running the app in my iOS device

4- Then, I'm opening Garage Band for iOS and looking to "Plug-ins & EQ" section finding for my Audio Unit and it isn't showing

...

5- If I enable Mac Catalyst, running the same app in my mac doesn't shows the Audio Unit in Garage Band for Mac either

I can see the Audio Unit in Garage Band of both app running Apple official example [available here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audio_unit_v3_plug-ins/creating_custom_audio_effects#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016185), but I can't figure out which detail I'm missing (I considerer that a plain empty project from Xcode templates should work straightforward, I've already worked with iMessage Extensions and that worked easy as that).
Any help?

Comment: Another related issue can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360087/audio-unit-v3-extension-doesnt-appear-in-host-apps/69529031#69529031

Answer (score 1):

You should run first of all the app installation and then the extension. This process works both for iOS and MacOS, but make sure if you're using MacOS Catalyst to create a MacOS Audio Unit extension for it, because it's different from iOS extension.